# how to get date_field value when error message show in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show the date value in the `date_field` when the post page, with errors, is rendered.

I've tried:

```
<%= f.date_field :start_at_date,:class=>"form-control fdate"
             ,value: Date.current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')%>
```

Which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<%= f.date_field :start_at_date,:class=>"form-control fdate", 
    value: model.errors.any? ? (Date.today):() %>
```

Replace "model" with your model name.